# Reading colours of cell in an excel sheet using python: openpyxl or any other library

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

Ok so here is what i need help with, i have an excel sheet and i have used the pattern fill as can be seen in the image below. So what i want to do in the python script is basically to read every row to check if the cell has a pattern fill and if it does use the values found in those particular cells to do something. I have already managed to do the first part which is to read the excel sheet using openpyxl.

[image: patternfill]

The sample of the code i have done thus far looks like this. I just need to fill up the step3: if () section if i need to import another library is fine just let me know what i need to do :)

```
    from openpyxl import load_workbook  

    #Step 3: Use this function to read the colours and do something
    def postDialog(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L):
        if (A == redcolorfill): #HERE How to read pattern fill color of cell

    #Step 1: Execute open excel workbook 
    ACTION1_File = load_workbook('Myfile.xlsx', )
    ACTION1_File_Sheet = ACTION1_File.get_sheet_names()[1]  
    ACTION1_File_Sheet_Name = ACTION1_File.get_sheet_by_name(ACTION1_File_Sheet)

    #Step 2: For every row read columns A-L and use in function postDialog
    for line in ACTION1_File_Sheet_Name.iter_rows():
        #Columns A - L
        postDialog(line[0].value, line[1].value, line[2].value, line[3].value, line[4].value, line[5].value, 
                   line[6].value, line[7].value, line[8].value, line[9].value, line[10].value, line[11].value)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how you can read the fill color of the cells

```
for line in ACTION1_File_Sheet_Name.iter_rows():
    for c in line:
        print(c.fill.bgColor)
```

EDIT: How to read a specific range

```
for c in ACTION1_File_Sheet_Name["A1:A10"]:
   print(c[0].fill.fgColor)
```

Comment: Wow that looks pretty straightforward but it shows me all the colours of all the cells in the excel sheet is there a way i can do it row by row like my sample above? Which i call another function to read line by line?

Comment: if i try to read line[0].value i get -> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fill'.......... if i try read line[0] -> TypeError: 'Cell' object is not iterable.... but i really want to be able to read the cell in the column i need for eg. column A

Comment: @Uraforclain: I am creating this code based on example given at https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/usage.html and searching within it. I am familiar with excel object model using vba and it is somewhat same for this package.

Comment: hmmm ok what i actually want is to read the entire row from A1 to L1 then proceed to A2 to L2 then read all the way till it ends. so if i edit the ["A1:L1"] its solved by how to keep running till the end of the file automatically

Comment: oh and the main thing is also after i know the cell is red i need to read the value of that cell to do something. but with this method i cant read the cell value

Comment: I think i can do it myself however one quick question the output i get is e.g. <openpyxl.styles.colors.Color object>
Parameters:
rgb='FFFF0000', indexed=None, auto=None, theme=None, tint=0.0, type='rgb'
How do i just get the "rgb='FFFF0000' part out?

Comment: `print(c[0].fill.fgColor.rgb)`