# Read entire row if a specific column has background color in excel sheet using Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, styleframe

I have an excel sheet which has few columns with background color. I need to fetch all rows which has background color in `column B`. I tried with `styleframe` but only able to pick specific cells from excel, not entire row.

```
from styleframe import StyleFrame, utils, Styler
cols = [1]
data = StyleFrame.read_excel(excel_file, read_style=True, use_openpyxl_style=false, usecols=cols)
print(data)
data.apply_style_by_index(data.index[1], Styler(bg_color='Yellow'), cols_to_style='Emp First Name')
print(data)
```

here is sample excel sheet

[image]

I am expecting whole rows (3,4,5,7,8,10,11,12 and 13), which has yellow background color in `column B`

Comment: will this one help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46382638/reading-colours-of-cell-in-an-excel-sheet-using-python-openpyxl-or-any-other-li

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('file.xlsx', data_only=True)
ws = wb['Sheet1']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Dept', 'FNAME','LNAME', '2021', '2022', '2023'])
for row in ws:
    if row[1].fill.start_color.index == "FFFFFF00":
        df.loc[len(df.index)] = [row[0].value, row[1].value, row[2].value, row[3].value, row[4].value, row[5].value]
```

The yellow cells ONLY in column B will be picked up and the whole row (all 6 columns) of that row will be added to a dataframe. You can proceed with further actions using the dataframe `df`.

My Excel sheet data:

[image: Excel data]

...and the output dataframe

```
>> df
Dept    FNAME   LNAME   2021    2022    2023
0   D2  User2   L2  100 200 300
1   D3  User3   L3  100 200 300
2   D4  User4   L4  100 200 300
3   D4  User8   L8  100 200 300
4   D2  User10  L10 100 200 300
5   D3  User11  L11 100 200 300
```